# How to display Image in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to load an image from webcam to display on pygame
I am using videocapture

```
from VideoCapture import Device
import pygame
import time
In=1
pygame.init()
w = 640
h = 480
size=(w,h)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) 

while True:
    cam = Device()
    cam.saveSnapshot(str(In)+".jpg") 
    img=pygame.image.load(In)
    screen.blit(img,(0,0))
    In=int(In)+1
    In=str(In)
```

Why does this not work.Pygame window opens but nothing displays?

Comment: is your image named 1.jpg and in the same folder?

Comment: dude if you look at the code you see that saveSnapshot(str(In)+".jpg")

Comment: you can use `pygame.camera` to take the pictures and remove the dependency on `VideoCapture`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to tell pygame to [update the display](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip).

Add the following line in your loop after blitting the image to the screen:

```
pygame.display.flip()
```

---

BTW, you probably want to limit how much images you take per second. Either use `time.sleep` or a [pygame clock](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock).

---

```
from VideoCapture import Device
import pygame
import time
In=1
pygame.init()
w = 640
h = 480
size=(w,h)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) 
c = pygame.time.Clock() # create a clock object for timing

while True:
    cam = Device()
    filename = str(In)+".jpg" # ensure filename is correct
    cam.saveSnapshot(filename) 
    img=pygame.image.load(filename) 
    screen.blit(img,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip() # update the display
    c.tick(3) # only three images per second
    In += 1
```