# How can I make SimpleCV show image?

Tags: python, simplecv

I am using the following code from Simple CV tutorial

```
logo = Image("simplecv")
logo.show()
```

But then it shows up a small window but blank, without image.

Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: works fine on my system. It shows simplcv's logo in a small window. Try re-installing simplecv

Answer (score 0):

just add a simple line in your code and it will work if you are running this code with a script file, otherwise just save an image on your desktop and provide the path of that image to your code "Image("path")" if still you are gating the same error please install it again.

```
logo = Image("simplecv")
logo.show()
raw_input("Press Enter for EXIT")
```

Answer (score -1):

This link helped me: [Image.show() won't display the picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279441/image-show-wont-display-the-picture)

For linux users: if you installed simpleCV from Software Center, then check if you have `sampleimages` folder in

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SimpleCV/
```

If it's not there, obtain it from

```
https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV#ubuntu-1204
```