# Installing xv utility on lubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL but **im.show()** is not working .I think because I not have installed xv utility .So I tried to intall in it ,I search for it on google I got many solution but they not seems to work for me. One of them is here I'm pasting .

```
sudo bash
cd /tmp
wget ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/xv/xv-3.10a.tar.gz
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/png-mng/xv-3.10a-jumbo-patches-20050501.tar.gz
wget http://bok.fas.harvard.edu/debian/xv/xv-3.10a-jumbo20050501-1.diff.gz tar xvzf xv-3.10a.tar.gz tar xvzf xv-3.10a-jumbo-patches-20050501.tar.gz
gzip -d xv-3.10a-jumbo20050501-1.diff.gz

cd xv-3.10a
patch -p1 < ../xv-3.10a-jumbo-fix-patch-20050410.txt
patch -p1 < ../xv-3.10a-jumbo-enh-patch-20050501.txt
patch -p1 < ../xv-3.10a-jumbo20050501-1.diff
apt-get install libxt-dev libc6-dev xlibs-dev libjpeg62-dev libtiff4-dev libpng12-dev
make cp xv /usr/local/bin
```

Here the Problem i stuck in that the links given for downloading are not working .They are not connecting .

So please if anyone knows any other mathod or any solution to install xv utility or to run im.show() without xv utility are welcome to give answer.

Thanks in Advance ...

Comment: To the best of my recollection, xv is an image viewer (with some small amount of editing capability) from the mid-90's that died out because of its non-free license. I don't think you really want xv. You just want an image viewer of some kind. [A similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279441/image-show-wont-display-the-picture) about python-imaging-library suggests imagemagick.

Comment: Is the PIL function im.show() will work wilth imagemagick????

Comment: Thanks Wumpus Q. Wumbley ,I installed imagmagick and it works for me .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the PIL library has "xv" hardcoded into it.  However, I just installed imagemagick and then did:

/usr/bin %   sudo ln -s display xv

Image.show() is working now, although I'm having some trouble with the screen size.