# Errors when trying to display images using PILLOW and EOG Image Viewer

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I am encountering an issue when using Python 3, Pillow and EOG Image Viewer. When I try and show the image using `image.show()`, an image viewer display box appears and says "No images found in file:///tmp/tmpsh4agi4s.PNG" at the top of the box. Occasionally an old image (not the same one that was loaded) is displayed instead of an error.

I have tried reinstalling eog and have looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279441/image-show-wont-display-the-picture). To me, it seems like it is not correctly writing the temporary image and therefore errors out when trying to display, but I could be wrong. Any insight is appreciated.

I am running Ubunutu 20.04.

This occurs even when running this simple code:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("people.jpg")
im.show()
```

Thanks in advance.